# Is "deep" an adverb in "They dug the well deep." or something else?

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech

> They dug the well deep.

What is "deep" in that sentence? I think its adverb but I stood wrong, help me someone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjective Used as an Adverb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81659/adjective-used-as-an-adverb)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's a good duplicate target.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also understand that sentence like this:

*They dug the well (to be | so it was) deep.*

in which case **deep** is a characteristic of the well, not a manner of digging.

Compare:

> They ate the fish raw.

P.S. Consider the following.  The parentheses around **to be** indicates that those words could be used in an actual statement but may be omitted without change of meaning.

> They wanted the well (to be) deep.

**deep** is a characteristic of the (intended) well, not of the wanting itself.

> So they dug the well (to be) deep.

Transitive **dig** here is directed (volitional or intentional) action.

Comment: Yes, deep is a characteristic of well in you form of that sentence.. But I don't think it is a characteristic of 'well', in simply " they dug the well deep ", it more seems like that of 'dug'..

Comment: http://udel.edu/~bruening/Downloads/DepictivesSCs1.pdf

Comment: @RajaAkmal Your interpretation is also possible in a slightly different kind of sentence: "They dug deep to make the well." In that case, *deep* should really be *deeply* and is an adverb.

Comment: @ArrowCase: No, "deep" doesn't need to be "deeply" in that case - "deep" can be an adverb, too (eg [see here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deep)).

Comment: I think a better comparison would be "They painted the barn red" as it has the same sense of the the subject altering the object in the specified manner.

Comment: @Kevin well you almost cleared it for me , thanks ☺

Comment: Consider also the idiom, "to run [someone] ragged". The expression implies that you are "running" someone until the adjective "ragged" applies, and not that the "running" itself is conducted "raggedly".

Comment: Also consider the example of [Jack Sprat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Sprat) (using slightly more modern english) "And so between the two of them, they licked the platter clean."

Comment: @RajaAkmal "The well is deep" is a valid, common sentence. Here, it should be obvious that "deep" is an adjective. "I dug the well [to be] deep" is the *same exact* usage of the word "deep". It's still an adjective that describes the well.

Comment: This is correct; it's an adjective.  Compare this with the sentence "They dug the trench shallow at one end and deep at the other".  This shows that digging something shallow is fine, and these words describe what you end up with, not the process.

Answer (score 3):

What is it exactly that makes you think that you're wrong? You certainly are on the right track with your assertion that it's an adverb. It definitely sounds like one. And one of the biggest reasons why it's an adverb and not any other part of speech has to do with the fact that it answers the following question:

> To what degree did they dig the well?

The answer would obviously be **"They dug the well deep."** or just **"Deep."** In other words, they dug the well to a great depth. As an adverb of degree, it modifies the verb *dug*, telling us to what degree the well was dug. It was dug deep.

---

If *deep* in the OP's example is an adjective modifying *the well*, as some people here are suggesting with no proof, because according to their logic when you dig a well deep, you end up with a deep well, then, what would happen if the sentence contained no noun phrases at all like this:

> Dig deep!

Is *deep* still an adjective? It can't be an adjective because there is no noun it can possibly modify. The verb *to dig* seems to work mostly with adverbs (e.g. **Try digging deeper.** - there is no object, as you can see, which means that *deeper* is the comparative form of the adverb *deep*) unlike some other verbs in English such as *paint* or *eat*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75530/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-rybkin-is-deep-an-adverb-in-they-dug-the-well).

Comment: "according to their logic when you dig a well deep, you end up with a deep well" - I don't think that's the logic.  The logic is that "deep" applies to "the well" and not to the manner of digging.  Yes, you can "dig deep(ly)", but that doesn't seem to be the actual usage here.  I'd say the original sentence is equivalent in meaning to "they dug a deep well", which makes it clear that "deep" is modifying "well".  It's equally valid to say "they dug a shallow well".

Comment: Adjectival "deep" in "They dug the well deep" is **not** modifier of "well" but complement of "dug". "Well" is direct object and "deep" is called the objective predicative complement, with "well" as predicand.

Answer (score 2):

If it were an adverb, it would be "deeply".  It's an object predicative like in "They painted the town red.", not describing a manner of doing but rather the end state of the sentence object.

Comment: As [psmears said elsewhere](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162535/is-deep-an-adverb-in-they-dug-the-well-deep-or-something-else/162542#comment325411_162542), *deep* can also be an adverb, without the -ly ending: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deep But you're correct it's not an adverb in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** It is possible to analyze *deep* as being an adjective or as an adverb.

### WHY

**Deep** can be either an adjective or an adverb because [not all adverbs end in -ly](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/do-all-adverbs-end-in-ly), some are indistinguishable from adjectives. Grammarians call them flat *adverbs*, so today we can advise someone to “drive safe” or “drive safely”, and to “stay close”. You can say that you “had a *bad* exam” (adj) or, informally, “did *bad* at the exam” (adv); however, most careful speakers will consider “did *badly* at the exam” to be the correct form.

> **Which Words Are Flat Adverbs?**
>
> Here’s a short list: “far,” “fast,” “hard,” “slow,” “quick,” “straight”, “clean,” “close,” **“deep,”** and “fine”. So go ahead and say, **“He kept** his cards **close”** or “Please sit tight.”
>
> Source: *Do All Adverbs End in -Ly?* By Grammar Girl

While **deep** can also be an adjective, ***deeply*** can never be an adjective.

> - “we **dug** DEEP” (adverb of manner) and “we dug a DEEP **hole**” (adj)
> - “**go** DEEP in the forest” (adverb of location), and ”went into the DEEP **forest**” (adj)
> - “be DEEPLY **moved**” (adverb of degree) or “feel a DEEP **sadness**” (adj)
> - but “a *deeply* forest” (WRONG) or “a *deeply* hole” (WRONG) are both ungrammatical.

Adverbs answer the following questions: *How? When? Where? How often?* and *Why?*

Consider the following examples, all the adverbs answer the question *how*:

> 1. They **dug** the well **good** = *good* is usually an adjective but in many American English dialects (if not all) it is also an adverb. Here it can either mean *well* or *completely and thoroughly*.
> 2. They **dug** the well **well** = *well* is an adverb, meaning “in a good or satisfactory way”
> 3. They **dug** the well **better** [this time] = this is the comparative form of the adverb *well*
> 4. They **dug** the well **best** = the superlative form of the adverb *well*
> 5. They **dug** the well **deep** = adverb of manner

The adverb *well* and its derivatives describe the verb *dig*, they are placed after the object.  They express the manner in which the action was performed.

- How did they dig **the well**?
- They dug **it** *good* and *deep*.

Furthermore, any of the following adverbs,  such as *slow/slowly*, *quick/quickly*, *competently*, *badly*, and *shoddily* could replace *deep*, e.g.

- They **dug** the well **slow**

Although *slow* is also an adjective, here it must be an adverb. We don't normally describe wells as being slow.

Furthermore, we can add another adverb to modify ‘deep’

6. *They dug the well **very** deep* OR *They dug the well **very** deeply* (both are correct)

If we replace *deep* with an appropriately similar adjective, the sentence is ungrammatical

7. They dug the well **very** large (NO)

Large is an adjective and as we all know **adjectives modify nouns** and pronouns.

8. They dug a very **large** well (YES)

Comment: *Drive safe* is an interesting example, actually.  My impression is that the flat adverb *safe* is restricted to non-standard speech, but *drive safe* seems to be an example of Standard English.  For some interesting discussion on the topic, see this Language Log post by Mark Liberman: [*Amid this vague uncertainty, who walks safe?*](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004231.html)